# Get sqlite query results by name - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to get the results of a SQL query by name and not by index. Here is the code I use to get the results by index:

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT distinct * from contents";

const char* queryUTF8 = [query UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

@autoreleasepool {
    int response = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, queryUTF8, -1, &statement, nil);
    if (response == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            Content * content=[[Content alloc]init];

            //Content Language

            if ( sqlite3_column_type(statement, 0) != SQLITE_NULL ){
                content.ID_ML = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            }
            else
                content.ID_ML = 0;

            if ( sqlite3_column_type(statement, 1) != SQLITE_NULL ){
                content.MAIN_ID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
            }
            else
                content.MAIN_ID = 0; 

            .
            .
            .
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Never use `*` for the column list in a `SELECT` statement. Explicitly list the columns by name so the returned data is known and in a known order.

Comment: This is the only way?

Comment: The query syntax I use is much more complex, I just wrote a simple example here.

Comment: Look into `sqlite3_column_name`.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I was looking for. If you want, reply as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Actually sqlite3_column_name still requires an index. It's possible to make it work but I will need two nested loops. Is there any more efficient way?